# Error :- Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' in android studio

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I newly Android project started a new default project. Everytime I try to start the app this error occurs:

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jdevani.validationdemo"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

build.gradle(project:EmerGencyHelp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

my error is

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: C:\Users\vfinava\Desktop\Project\EmerGencyHelp\app\src\main\java\com\example\vfinava\emergencyhelp\DataHelper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.684 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

please help me
Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you show us DataHelper.java  file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you dont add suport-v4 library correctly in your project.
Check this :

1. you have add this library to all modules that need it (If you have
   more than module in your project like main module and library
   module).
2. Check that you dont add this library twice.

Finally if this didn't resolve your problem try to remove this library from your imported libraries list and your project modules dependency list and import and add it again from **one source** to your project , then try rebuild the project or restart the IDE.
I hope this way can help you :)

Comment: I saw this error a lot and as i can see in your question your `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION`  is about support v4 library !

Comment: see my last sentences of my answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

The log trace have said: `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;`. This is caused by some caches. Not anything wrong with your codes. You just need to `rebuild Project` or `clean Project`, then everything would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of issue happens when your are using **the same library with a different version**.

Remove from your libs folder the supportv4.jar and add this line in the `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not because of JDK 1.8 or 1.7, Its due to dependencies. Please check your Gradle Dependencies.

I have faced similar issue, in my case the problem was occurred due to Facebook dependency

dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    //Commented the following one
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
after commenting the above line everything was normal

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are using same package which may be deprecated and came up with new name. and possibility that you install both of them.
or
may be same package with different version is installed.