# Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This is my first time i am working with android studio and trying to build application. this is my build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pack.get.global.googlegsm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

but when I try to execute the application I get following error:

```
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I surfed and found that there is possibility of duplicate jar files. or dependencies hot should I fix this problem?

Comment: Use multidex https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: I tried it is giving same error..

Comment: The issue is clear. You have more than 65536 methods. You have to implement the multidex as described in the official doc. Check all steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some jar in the libs folder ? The instructions

> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile all that has jar extension on libs folder. So check it.

I had your problem right now, I solved it checking the dependencies ( I had one library with different version of the same dependence) and rebuild the project.

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361693/error-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-in-android-studio/29361914#29361914).

So try:

1- Check dependecies and resolve the different versions or conflicts of the same library/dependence

2- Resync Gradle

**3- Rebuild the project** (this was essential for me)

Sometimes it seems that the problem is caused by the exhaustion of RAM memory (a lot of program opened or android emulator)