# jdk1.8.0 finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, stripe-payments, build.gradle

My error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have zero clue where this is coming from. I'm trying to integrate Stripe so possibly it could be a gradle issue.

Stripe is a external library integrated.

App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.weaverprojects.stripe2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':stripe')
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.13'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
}
```

Stripe library build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-java:1.15.1'
    //compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }  
}
```

Settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':stripe'
```

Comment: If you go to `File -> Project Structure` (Assuming you're using android studio) what is the JDK location set to?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51

And I can do a "cd /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51" and get to a folder

Comment: And you're on a windows computer, no?

Comment: I've tried on a window, linux and mac. Gradle can sync fine, just when its being built.

Comment: If you try add `multiDexEnabled = true` to your build.gradle's `defaultConfig` section, does that let it build?

Comment: I put it in stripe library build.gradle file and still got the issue. I then added also to the app and got:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.`

`> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class`

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem right now, I solved it checking the dependencies ( I had one library with different version of the same dependence) and rebuild the project.

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361693/error-execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-in-android-studio/29361914#29361914).

So try:

1- Check dependecies and resolve the different versions or conflicts of the same library/dependence

2- Resync Gradle

**3- Rebuild the project** (this was essential for me)

Sometimes it seems that the problem is caused by the exhaustion of RAM memory (a lot of program opened or android emulator)